# How to add external .jar to android project? (with certain conditions)

Tags: java, android, ant, jar

I need to add some external .jar files to my android project BUT

1) without using Eclipse or any other IDE (so no .classpath)

2) without copying them to /libs folder, i need them to stay where they are

How can i accomplish that? I know that ant should have this functionality but and cant find it. It would be great if there is something like adding "android.library.reference" to project.properties but for .jar instead of library project.

Comment: create a symbolic link in libs.

Comment: Also have a look at Maven - [link](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev.html)

Comment: good but i use jni in my project and i heard that maven don't done like these

Comment: that's as easy as it gets.

Comment: "without using Eclipse or any other IDE (so no .classpath)" -- then what are you using to build with? Gradle? Ant? Maven?

Comment: ant, i mentioned it in my post

Comment: I would recommend that you move off of Ant and onto anything else. Google has gone with Gradle; others use Maven. If you insist upon Ant, you will need to do with njzk2 suggests.

Comment: Add line android.library.reference.1=.path_to_jar to 'project.properties'. If you use ant build,xml, the jar will be included.

Comment: @cyanide sorry dude, but that works only for library projects. it doesn't work for .jar files

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure that it will work for you but you can use this

```
    <path id="class.path">
      <fileset dir="jar_folder">
         <include name="**/*.jar" />
     </fileset>
   </path>
```

and you can use it in **javac** command as

```
<javac executable="${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac"  encoding="utf-8" srcdir="src/" destdir="temp/" debug="on" debuglevel="lines,source,var" fork="true" memoryInitialSize="256m" memoryMaximumSize="1024m">
        <classpath refid="class.path" />
    </javac>
```